# MySQL concat multiple row under one ID

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table called `mst_order_details` and it has column (order no) and it can be same order no it more time.

Each order number have related technique column I want to concat technique column according to order no

**mst_order_details** table :

```
order no   Technique
-------------------------
1           heat_seal
1           laser_cut
1           oil_filter
2           diamond cut
2           diamond cut
```

Output should be like this :

```
order no    Technique
---------------------------------------------
 1          heat_seal/laser_cut/ oil_filter
 2          diamond cut
```

Comment: post your database structure, need more explaination

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Research, try something, add your code & point your problem. Pay attention to formatting question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use GROUP_CONCAT:

```
SELECT `order no`, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `Technique` SEPARATOR '/') FROM mst_order_details GROUP BY `order no`;
```

Comment: you should add DISTINCT to technique, no?

Comment: @backbone it depends on requirements

Comment: he wanted the row 2    | diamond_cut to show up only one time in the answer.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I missed it.

Comment: thank you very much for the quick response and support  ...it worked .